# Exclude edges of a cylinder from a displacement map

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

Is there a way in three js to restrict the displacement map to affect only the faces of a cylinder, but keep the edges of the cylinder in the same place?

I'm trying to make a cake with a slice cut out and want to give the frosting some detail, but with the displacement map the edges no longer meet up.

The cake is dynamically resized, which is why I don't want to make custom models in Blender.

[image: Cake with displacement]

Cake with displacement map.

[image: cake with no displacement]

Cake without displacement map.